# MimeKit, C#, lock IdleAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mimekit

I dont understand, why this not working? How I can get access to object? I want use code in `lock` in event `Inbox_CountChanged`. Help me please.

```
currentOperationTioken = new CancellationTokenSource();
client = new ImapClient();

client.Connected += Client_Connected;

client.Authenticated += Client_Authenticated;

client.Connect("my impa", 993, true);
client.Authenticate("login", "pass");

inbox = client.Inbox.GetSubfolder("some");

inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

inbox.CountChanged += Inbox_CountChanged;

client.IdleAsync(currentOperationTioken.Token);

lock (client.SyncRoot)
{
    foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen))
    {
        //var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
        Console.WriteLine(inbox.GetMessage(uid).Subject);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(inbox.Count);
}
```

I get next error :

> The ImapClient is currently busy processing a command in another
>   thread. Lock the SyncRoot property to properly synchronize your
>   threads.

Comment: IdleAsync returns a Task that needs to be awaited. This is the concurrent operation.

Comment: @Hylaean Please, it is possible more in detail? ((